# How can I securely hide my API keys in ASP.net with React without using Azure Key Vault or User Secrets Manager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I am making a web-app using ASP.net with React as the front-end, and I am having difficulty finding information on how to secure my API keys safely. I want to be able to send GET and POST requests securely to the NASA API to retrieve data without revealing my personal key. If it helps, I do not have a database for the project, and will be using an ASP.net Controller and Model to handle the API calls.

I have tried the User Secrets manager provided by ASP.net, but it is only suitable for development as the keys are not encrypted (from my understanding). I am not particularly interested in using the Azure key vault services to secure all of my future API keys either. Are there any other solutions?

*NASA API:* (https://api.nasa.gov/)

*User Secrets manager:* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows)

*Azure key vault services:* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: The only way to keep the keys a secret is to use them in the server-side api layer, never client-side. You will not make the api calls directly from React, you will call your api which makes the calls to nasa.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use the Azure Key Vault?

Comment: I would like to find another way to do this because I just can't imagine the only way to safely secure your private keys in ASP.net production is by handing over credit card information (even for the free tier of Azure Services) to Microsoft.